# Range of dates based on system date within a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am attemping to write a case statement which will filter a range of dates based on the current system date. I need a range from 30 days ago to current, 30-60 days ago, and 60-120 days ago, all based on the system date. This is what I have no far which is proving unsuccessful:

```
(case 
 when a.last_active_date between sysdate and sysdate-30 then 'Inactive 30 Days or Less'
 when a.last_active_date between sysdate-30 and sysdate-60 then 'Inactive 30-60' 
 when a.last_active_date between sysdate-60 and  sysdate - 120 then 'Inactive 60-120' 
 else 'Inactive 120+ Days'
 end) Inactivity,
```

Any suggestions as to how I should approach this?

Comment: Besides the fact that those ranges overlap because `between` is inclusive, in what way is the query unsuccessful?

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL, this kind of thing is usually better handled at the application layer.  Also, what's up with the two different tags - which RDBMS is it?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - Besides the overlapping it is not filtering correctly

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I am loading raw data into Spotfire, I'm not sure how else I would do this. This is an oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in PL-SQL: [DB Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=803d5cbfdc4e7dd3fc30648af2948fb5)

```
-- select based on runtime calculation
select a.last_active_date
,   case 
        when (sysdate - a.last_active_date) <= 30 then 'Inactive 30 Days or Less'
        when (sysdate - a.last_active_date) <= 60 then 'Inactive 30-60' 
        when (sysdate - a.last_active_date) <= 120 then 'Inactive 60-120' 
        else 'Inactive 120+ Days'
 end Inactivity
from demo a
order by a.last_active_date desc
```

Here's an answer in T-SQL: [DB Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d3a6129a823958dca4d336471018c47)

```
select a.last_active_date
,   case 
        when getutcdate() - a.last_active_date <= 30 then 'Inactive 30 Days or Less'
        when getutcdate() - a.last_active_date <= 60 then 'Inactive 30-60' 
        when getutcdate() - a.last_active_date <= 120 then 'Inactive 60-120' 
        else 'Inactive 120+ Days'
 end Inactivity
from @t a
order by a.last_active_date desc
```

Here's the code to setup the above example with test data:

```
declare @t table (last_active_date datetime)

insert @t select getutcdate()
union select getutcdate()-29
union select getutcdate()-30
union select getutcdate()-31
union select getutcdate()-59
union select getutcdate()-60
union select getutcdate()-61
union select getutcdate()-119
union select getutcdate()-120
union select getutcdate()-121
```

The advantage of this is the reuse of the `getutcdate() - a.last_active_date` function should allow the caching of the result, so should save on some calculation overhead.

Comment: Cache the result per-`CASE` statement, maybe (don't know enough of SQL Server to say for sure).  Cache for an indexable search, no.  You're outputting all the rows anyways, so it's not as big a deal as it might be otherwise, though.

Comment: Agreed it will (probably) only be cached per row so won't make a huge amount of difference, but any optimisation's helpful.